# where to modify get_comment_author_link()?

Tags: comments

Whenever a user presses on a comments author it redirects the user to the site which was enetered by user. I just want to add the target="_blank" element. where I can modify this?

In file i see only this: get_comment_author_link()

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use the `get_comment_author_link` filter for this in the following manner.

```
add_filter( "get_comment_author_link", "wpse_63316_modifiy_comment_author_anchor" );
function wpse_63316_modifiy_comment_author_anchor( $author_link ){
    return str_replace( "<a", "<a target='_blank'", $author_link );
}
```

Comment: Just tested this solution and longer works.

Answer (score 0):

**Add an custom** class to comment_author_link. When using 'get_comment_author_link' this function to fetch comment author link.

Just add this code into functions.php

```php
// filter for get_comment_author_link
function custom_get_comment_author_link($content)
{
    $extra_classes = 'text-decoration-none text-primary fw-bold mb-0';
    return preg_replace('/url/', 'url ' . $extra_classes, $content);
}

add_filter('get_comment_author_link', 'custom_get_comment_author_link', 99);
```