# How to change commenter links to /user/user_id?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, comments, comments-template

I would like to change the commenter links as shown in this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

In [my test plugin at GitHub](https://github.com/afarber/wp-newbie/blob/master/wp-city-gender/wp-city-gender.php) I have first tried the following code:

```
define('PROFILE', '<a href="/user/%s" rel="external nofollow" class="url">%s</a>');

function get_comment_author_link($cid) {
   $uid = get_comment_author($cid);
   return sprintf(PROFILE, $uid->ID, $uid->name);
}

add_action('get_comment_author_link',  'get_comment_author_link');
```

But then by studying the file `wp-includes/comment-template.php` I have realized, that the argument to `get_comment_author_link` is not a comment ID, but a string containing `<a href="...">...</a>` and thus I can't use this hook for my purpose (because the user ID can't be found in the hook).

Please advise me a suitable hook or way to change the commenter links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`get_comment_author_link`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L201) hook, which is part of the [`get_comment_author_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_comment_author_link) template tag, like your question already suggests. Then you only have to get the according `user_id`, which can be done via the `$comment` global, and construct the link you want accordingly.

Exemplary usage like shown below:

```
add_filter( 'get_comment_author_link', 'wpse144835_custom_comment_author_link' );
function wpse144835_custom_comment_author_link( $link ) {
    global $comment;
    $comment_user_id = $comment->user_id;
    // code to create the new link
    return $new_link;
}
```

---

**Edit:**

Responding regarding your questions, the according comment is unfortunately deleted, so this is kind of a informational shortlist now. There is a lot in there, way too much to really answer them, but I give you some additional information:

- As we have the global available you can use `$comment->comment_author`
- As for functions, you can use [`get_comment_author()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment_author) or [`comment_author()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_author) depending on your need to `return` or `echo`.
- At the [Codex: Global Variables](http://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables) you can get an overview about them
- There is the [`WP_Comment_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Comment_Query) and the `Walker_Comment` class
- For example at the comment_author codex page is a list of [comment related functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_author#Comments_Functions)
- Additionally I'd suggest you look through the [`comment-template.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L0) and the [`comment.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/comment.php#L0) to learn more about all of that

Comment: Thanks for the references! (Sorry, I've occasionally deleted my old comment - after I've found `$comment->comment_author`). I will gladly award the bounty in a day.

Comment: Ohh, sure, how could I've forgot about that! @AlexanderFarber

Comment: Could you please take 1 more look at my site http://slova.de/archives/29 - both the users "Mr. WordPress" and the user "aaa" (someone registered at my site) have the `/user/0`. Why do they both have their ID == 0?

Comment: `0` means that it is a comment by unregistered user; the user mr. wordpress doesn't exist, so it's a unregistered comment, what about your aaa user? @AlexanderFarber

Comment: Correct, the user "aaa" doesn't exist either - this explains the ID == 0. (Sorry, I don't know WordPress well yet and was assuming everyone needs to register before commenting)

Comment: Not a problem, I'm still learning every day. It depends on your setup under *Settings > Discussion*. If you want unregistered comments you probably should implement a condition for that, because the profile page only will only work for registered users. @AlexanderFarber

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

```
 $id = get_comment( get_comment_ID() )->user_id;
```

I just found this solution while googling, but I don't have an environment to test it out.

Comment: This should work, but there are unnecessary steps in it.

Answer (score 0):

The *output* of that function, is an a-tag containing a link to the author profile, its input is definitely an ID.

If you'd like to change the output of that function, you need a filter and you'd need to str_replace the a-tag (or similar method acting on the string). (see [where to modify get_comment_author_link()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63316/where-to-modify-get-comment-author-link))

I think the more important question is: what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

In theory the commenters link could be implemented differently in every theme/plugin. It could be done with get_comment_author_url() or retrieved straight from the comment object with get_comment(), or any other way really.

However to alter the output of get_comment_author_link(), see the example above.